# What is wrong with ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

Why does this plot have a big blank hole in it?

```
ContourPlot[
    PDF[BinormalDistribution[0.8], {v1, v2}], {v1, -4, 4}, {v2, -4, 4}, 
    PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Comment: It is just a cut-off. Try to add the option `PlotRange -> {0., 0.3}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify `PlotRange -> All` to avoid clipping in the "z"-axis (if you don't know the z-range beforehand):

```
ContourPlot[ PDF[BinormalDistribution[0.8], {v1, v2}],
    {v1, -4, 4}, {v2, -4, 4}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]